# NGINX - How would I set expires headers for all virtual hosts?

Tags: nginx, header, config

I'm looking for a way to set server wide expires headers so that all existing or new virtual hosts will be configured the same.  Unfortunately, I can not do this in each virtual host's conf file, so I am looking for a way to make the following directives server wide.

```
location ~* .(ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|css|rss|atom|js|jpg
              |jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid
              |midi|wav|bmp|rtf)$ {
    expires max;
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `expires` directive can be placed in the `http` block and is therefore inherited by all server blocks and their location blocks.

The manual shows an example of using the `expires` directive with a `map` variable. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#expires).

You could use `$request_uri` rather than `$sent_http_content_type` to match your existing regex and achieve identical behaviour with:

```
map $request_uri $expires {
    default off;
    ~*\.(ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|css|rss|atom|js|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf)(\?|$) max;
}    
expires $expires;
```

Both directives placed inside the `http` block but outside any `server` block.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map) for details.

Comment: Thanks! That worked.  You had an extra parentheses `...|rtf))(\?|$) max;` should be `...|rtf)(\?|$) max;`