# Nginx root directive inside location doesn't seem to be working

Tags: nginx, configuration, nginx-location

nginx version: nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)
built with OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
TLS SNI support enabled
Installed via apt-get
using html5 boilerplate config project as a base

I have been trying to do a simple task and it is not working like I thought it would.  I have a directory structure like so:

```
/var/www$ tree
.
├── docroot
│   └── files
│       ├── booger.txt
│       └── favicon.ico
└── static
    ├── h5bp
    │   ├── humans.txt
    │   ├── js
    │   │   ├── main.js
    │   │   ├── plugins.js
    │   │   └── vendor
    │   │       ├── jquery-1.12.0.min.js
    │   │       └── modernizr-2.8.3.min.js
    │   ├── tile.png
    │   └── tile-wide.png
```

I thought the best approach was to have a server root of the docroot/files (the real docroot) and then redefine the root for the static files.  Here is my default config in /etc/nginx/sites-available:

```
# Choose between www and non-www, listen on the *wrong* one and redirect to
# the right one -- http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls#Server_Name
#
server {
  listen [::]:80 default_server;
  listen 80 default_server;

  # listen on all hosts
  server_name _;

  # and redirect to the https host (declared below)
  # avoiding http://www -> https://www -> https:// chain.
  return 301 https://www.ubercode.io$request_uri;
}

server {

  # listen [::]:443 ssl http2 accept_filter=dataready;  # for FreeBSD
  # listen 443 ssl http2 accept_filter=dataready;  # for FreeBSD
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2 deferred default_server;  # for Linux
  listen 443 ssl http2 deferred default_server;  # for Linux
  # listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
  # listen 443 ssl http2;

  # The host name to respond to
  server_name www.ubercode.io;

  include h5bp/directive-only/ssl.conf;

#  root /var/www/docroot/files;
  root /var/www;
  index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    # return forbidden for any php, asp, jsp, our .dt templates, or myadmin requests
#    location ~ (\.dt$|myadmin|\.php$|\.jsp$|\.asmx$|\.asp$) {
#       deny all;
#    }

#    location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
#        expires 1d;
#    }
#    location ~*  \.(pdf)$ {
#        expires 5d;
#    }

  # static
  location /static/ {
#    root /var/www;
    autoindex on;
#     expires 1d;
  }

  location / {
    alias /var/www/docroot/files;
    autoindex on;
  }
  #Specify a charset
  charset utf-8;

  # Custom 404 page
  error_page 404 /404.html;

  # Include the basic h5bp config set
  include h5bp/basic.conf;
}

server {
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
  listen 443 ssl http2;

  # listen on the wrong host
  server_name _;

  include h5bp/directive-only/ssl.conf;

  # and redirect to the non-www host (declared below)
  return 301 https://www.ubercode.io$request_uri;
}
```

If I use it like it is shown, the static files work but the alias at the root does not seem to work as they throw a 404.  If I comment the alias under the / location and the /var/www server root then uncomment the other lines the server returns docroot/files assets but no static files.  It just seems like the overriding root inside a location block doesn't work.  Can anyone explain whats going on and possibly give me some direction to how to fix it?

Comment: So, it appears that what I said above is not exactly true.  For some reason, when I put the url for booger.txt in my browser I do get results but favicon.ico does not.  I also tested with a jpeg and html file but no joy.  But for some reason the booger.txt file does work.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I use it like it is shown, the static files work but the alias at
>   the root does not seem to work as they throw a 404.

You should not use an `alias` directive in the `location /` statement. Use a `root` statement with the same value instead.

> If I comment the alias under the / location and the /var/www server
>   root then uncomment the other lines the server returns docroot/files
>   assets but no static files.

If you enable the `location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$`, then it will override the `location /static/` block, and setting any value for `root` within the latter will be ignored. Also, it will override the `location /` block for URIs ending with `.ico` so `/favicon.ico` will no longer work as it's from a different document root.

See [how `nginx` processes a request](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html) and note that regular expression locations take precedence over prefix locations.

If you need to fine tune the `expires` value, you cannot add `location` blocks without considering which document root they influence.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36222115/nginx-how-would-i-set-expires-headers-for-all-virtual-hosts/36223606#36223606) for an alternative approach, using a `map` directive to set the `expires` value based on the `$request_uri`.

Comment: Thank you for your response Richard.  If I change the alias to root in the / location block I still get the same results.  It is almost like the root directive inside a location block doesn't get applied.  Your other comments are with an expires header which is commented out.  This doesn't show or point me to anything that will allow me to host 2 different docroot locations.

Comment: I am giving Richard credit because after researching a little, his answer is true.  You should use root instead of alias to prevent a regex lookup.  However, if anyone visits later, the problem has something to do with the html5 boilerplate config project.  It is overriding images and such somewhere which caused the problem.  Going back to a base install fixed things.