# Debian 9 - nginx ignores location block

Tags: nginx, debian, config

The following is the content of my mydomain.conf file of nginx.

```
server {
    server_name  www.mywebsite.com;

#the below works
add_header "this" "works";

    root /var/www/yii2app/web;
    index index.php;

    charset utf-8;
    access_log  off;
    error_log   off;

    location ~* \.(txt|js|json|css|png|jpg|gif|swf|ico|pdf|mov|fla|zip|rar|svg)$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
    }

    location /img {
        add_header Cache-Control "public, no-transform";
        add_header "hello" "word";
        expires max;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /var/www/yii2app/web/$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

}
```

I was trying to configure cache-control, when I realised that my location blocks are not being read or honoured by nginx.

I tested this by putting some extra header key-values such as:

```
add_header "this" "works";
```

and

```
add_header "hello" "word";
```

I can see "this" "works", when I test using curl, but not "hello" "world", which is within the /img location block...

```
curl -I http://www.mywebsite.com/img/test.gif
```

What am I doing wrong? The above config is the exact config I have at the moment, except the website address and root path. I have commented out every other config lines.

Comment: The request is handled by the `location ~* \.(txt|js|json|css|png|jpg|gif|swf|ico|pdf|mov|fla|zip|rar|svg)$` block and not the `location /img` block.

Comment: @RichardSmith Yes, I just noticed that as well, but putting a random header in all blocks. Is there any way I can make /img/ block be considered and not the other?

I even tried to move the /img/ above to no avail. Please suggest how I should have my config set up

Comment: The `^~` modifier will give a prefix location a greater precedence than all the regular expression locations. Try `location ^~ /img` and see [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

Comment: That works, I guess you could post it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regular expression location blocks are evaluated in order and take precedence over normal prefix location blocks.

The URI `/img/foo.gif` will match the `location ~* \.(txt|js|json|css|png|jpg|gif|swf|ico|pdf|mov|fla|zip|rar|svg)$` block in preference to the `location /img` block, irrespective of order.

You can give a prefix location a greater precedence by using the `^~` modifier.

For example:

```
location ^~ /img { ... }
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

Alternatively, if you do not need the `add_header` part, you can use a [`map` with the `expires` directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36222115/nginx-how-would-i-set-expires-headers-for-all-virtual-hosts/36223606#36223606).