# Add header on specific path when reverse proxying node.js app

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

How can I add specific header based on request path when I am reverse proxying a node.js app?

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name DOMAIN;
        set $server_root /var/www/app;

        location /static {
                expires 7d;
                alias $server_root/static;
        }
        location /favicon.ico {
                expires 7d;
                alias $server_root/static/favicon.ico;
        }

        location / {
                #location = / {
                #        expires 7d;
                #}
                proxy_http_version      1.1;
                proxy_cache_bypass      $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade                        $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection             "upgrade";
                proxy_set_header Host                           $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For        $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto      $scheme;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host       $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port       $server_port;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8763;
        }
        client_max_body_size 15M;
}
```

The code above is my current nginx configuration, and I tried to use `location = /` to add have a different expiration time on my home page. But uncommenting that just gives me "/index.html not found", so I thought `location = /` won't proxy it correctly. So, what should I use to add header on specific path and still make reverse proxy work?

Comment: What happens if you use an `expires`  directive inside the first `location` block without nested one? For me, it appends `Cache-Control` and `Expires` headers to response (my server is openresty 1.15.8.2, based on nginx 1.15.8 core), however my upstream doesn't return this headers in its own response.

Comment: You could use a map instead and set `expires` to the value of the map. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36222115/nginx-how-would-i-set-expires-headers-for-all-virtual-hosts/36223606#36223606)